# Sorting doubly linked list alphabetical

Tags: c, sorting, doubly-linked-list

The task is to sort a list in alphabetical order. That is to be done by changing the pointer variables and not just switching the content of the nodes.

I first wanted to implemend a swap function. that function shall swap 2 nodes. After that I wanted to implement a sorting algorithm. My problem is, that the swaping function does not really work as it should and the algorithm doesnt either (ofc, since the swapping function doesnt even work).

```
    struct student {
      char Vorname[51];
      char Nachname[51];
      int MatNr;
      char Adresse[51];
      int Kurse;
      struct student *next;
      struct student *previous;
    };

    struct student *first = NULL;
    struct student *last = NULL;  

    void swap(struct student *pointer) {
      struct student *pointer1, *pointer3, *pointer4;
      pointer1 = pointer->previous;
      pointer3 = pointer->next;
      pointer4 = pointer->next->next;

      pointer4->previous = pointer;
      pointer->next = pointer4;
      pointer1->next = pointer3;
      pointer3->previous = pointer1;
      pointer->previous = pointer3;
      pointer3->next = pointer;
    }
```

This is the not finished sort function. I didnt implement it correctly yet, since the swap function took my attention first.

```
void sort(void) {
  struct student *pointer1, *pointer2, *pointer3, *pointer4;
  pointer1 = first->previous;
  pointer2 = pointer1->next;
  pointer3 = pointer2->next;
  pointer4 = pointer3->next;

  while(pointer2 != NULL){
    if((strcmp(pointer2->Nachname, pointer3->Nachname)) > 0) {
           swap(pointer2);
    }
    pointer1 = pointer1->next;
    printList();
  }
}
```

When I run `swap(first);` the first element doesnt get displayed since the pointer `first` is now pointing at the second node. Well, thats easily done with `first = pointer3;`

When I run `swap(first->next);` there is a similar problem, since it also leaves out one node of the list.

I'm not really sure how to get this function right, since `first` shouldnt get involved in swapping the 2nd and 3rd node of the list.

I'd appreciate any help that could help me solving this, maybe I'm just overlooking some minor mistake, but I can't really get the solution of this.
Thank you!

Comment: Why does your swap function only accepts one argument?

Comment: Why not use an ordered insert function and re-insert all the nodes into "new" list?

Comment: My swap function only accepts one element, since it should only swap 2 neighbour elements. 

And I didnt use insertsort, since the task was to especially swap the nodes and use strcmp with it. ^^

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] from your code. That means a single file, a `main()` that sets up fixed data content and then runs the swap operation, so everyone can easily reproduce the faulty behaviour. Note that many parts of you `struct student` definition are not necessary and they only distract from the problem.

Comment: As answered below, merge sort is more efficient, but to help with the issue of swapping nodes, there's a difference if the nodes are adjacent or not. Common code can be used for both cases if whatever points to the two nodes is swapped first (the linkage from other nodes or head or tail pointers), then the nodes pointers swapped next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting the list by swapping doubly linked nodes seems quite inefficient because you cannot use fast algorithms like merge sort.

You could instead use only the `next` links in a recursive merge sort function and reconstruct the back links on the resulting list.

Here is how to do it:

```
struct student {
    char Vorname[51];
    char Nachname[51];
    int MatNr;
    char Adresse[51];
    int Kurse;
    struct student *next;
    struct student *previous;
};

struct student *first = NULL;
struct student *last = NULL;

/* Merge two sorted lists. p1 and p2 are != NULL */
struct student *merge(struct student *p1, struct student *p2) {
    struct student *head, **pp;
    pp = &head;
    for (;;) {
        if (strcmp(p1->Nachname, p2->Nachname) <= 0) {
            *pp = p1;
            pp = &p1->next;
            p1 = p1->next;
            if (p1 == NULL) {
                *pp = p2;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            *pp = p2;
            pp = &p2->next;
            p2 = p2->next;
            if (p2 == NULL) {
                *pp = p1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return head;
}

/* Recursive top-down merge sort */
struct student *msort(struct student *np) {
    struct student *p1, *p2;
    /* trivial lists are sorted */
    if (np == NULL || np->next == NULL)
        return np;
    /* locate mid-point using 2 finger method */
    for (p1 = np, p2 = np->next; p2 && p2->next; p2 = p2->next->next)
        p1 = p1->next;
    /* split the list at mid-point */
    p2 = p1->next;
    p1->next = NULL;
    p1 = np;
    /* sort the sublists recursively */
    p1 = msort(p1);
    p2 = msort(p2);
    return merge(p1, p2);
}

void sort(void) {
    struct student *p1, *p2;
    /* sort the list as a singly linked list */
    first = msort(first);
    /* reconstruct the backlinks */
    p1 = NULL;
    for (p2 = first; p2; p2 = p2->next) {
        p2->last = p1;
        p1 = p2;
    }
    last = p1;
}
```

As suggested by *rcgldr*, it may be more efficient to use a bottom-up merge sort to avoid repeated scans of the lists. Here is the alternate code:

```
/* bottom-up merge sort with sublist array */
struct student *msort(struct student *head) {
    struct student *array[32] = { NULL };
    int i;

    /* handle trivial lists */
    if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL)
        return head;

    i = 0;  /* avoid warning */
    p1 = head;
    /* merge nodes into pending lists of increasing lengths */
    while (head != NULL) {
        struct student *next = head->next;
        head->next = NULL;
        for (i = 0; i < 32 && array[i] != NULL; i++) {
            head = merge(array[i], head);
            array[i] = NULL;
        }
        /* do not go past end of array */
        if (i == 32)
            i--;
        array[i] = head;
        head = next;
    }
    /* merge pending lists into single list:
     * the last element stored into the array is at offset i and
     * all entries before it are NULL pointers. */
    for (head = array[i++]; i < 32; i++) {
        if (array[i] != NULL)
            head = merge(array[i], head);
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: I tried to run the code but it gives me an error at the srot function, since `p2->last` is not in the struct structure.
I didnt think of mergesort, so thank you, that does make sense. ^^

Comment: @Shiroyuki: my mistake... use `previous` instead of `last`.

Comment: hm, tried that already but then i get an error that the recipe failed for target 'all'.

Comment: @Shiroyuki: you should post the complete code of a compilable program.

Comment: Bottom up merge sort is more efficient than top down merge sort since it eliminates all the scanning used to split lists. Wiki has example code for [bottom up merge sort for linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) .

Comment: @rcgldr: that's correct. The number of comparisons is higher with bottom-up merge than top-down merge for list lengths not powers of two, but the it does save iterating multiple times over the list and recursion overhead.

Comment: @rcgldr: I added the bottom-up alternative. Indeed a more efficient approach.

Comment: The edited top-down version works for me now too, thank you!

Comment: @chqrlie - Unlike bottom up merge sort for arrays, if the number of nodes in a linked list is not a power of 2, the internal array ends up with some null entries, and I'm not sure what affect this has on the number of compares.

Comment: @rcgldr: merged sublists always have equal sizes, all powers of 2 during the main loop. The final merge loop may merge lists of very different sizes, which is somewhat suboptimal. Think of the pathological case where the list has 2^n+1 elements: the final loop performs an insertion sort on the full 2^n sublist for a single element, which can cost up to n comparisons. Furthermore, the number of comparisons is constant (n log n) for any list length in the top-down algorithm, whereas it depends on the contents of the list in the bottom-up case for non powers of 2 lengths.

Comment: @chqrlie - The overhead of scanning depends on the nature of the input list. If the input list nodes are in memory order, then scanning will be cache friendly. If the input list is large, and the nodes are scattered, then worst case is a cache miss on every node access during scanning.  To create such a list, I sorted a large (16 million nodes) linked list with pseudo random data, resulting in a scattered list. Then I filled the scattered list with another set of of pseudo random data, and sorted that. A scattered list also presents the same cache issue during merges of sub-lists.

Comment: @chqrlie - doing a performance comparison, with 2^24 + 1 = 16777217 nodes (using pseudo random 64 bit integers). Top down, 381438748 compares, non-scattered run time 6.109 seconds, scattered run time 23.016 seconds. Bottom up, 383435797 compares (0.5% more compares), non-scattered run time 6.502 seconds (top down faster, bottom up ~1.065 longer than top down), scattered run time 11.243 seconds (bottom up faster, top down ~2.047 longer than bottom up)

Comment: @chqrlie - since this is a doubly linked list, a single post sort pass will be needed to set the previous pointers. I did another comparison with 2^20 + 1 = 1048577 nodes, td => 19645414 compares, non-scattered 0.173 seconds, scattered 0.596 seconds, bu => 20621979 compares (5% more), non-scattered 0.157 seconds (bu only 1 clock tick faster), scattered 0.353 seconds (td 68% longer). Not sure performance matters when run time is less than 0.6 seconds for td.

Comment: @rcgldr: Thank you for the benchmarks, this confirms my intuition, td being only marginally faster than bu for select cases. bu is definitely a better choice as its performance is more reliable in general, especially for scattered lists as you have shown.